# is there any way to find text using dimensions using pymupdf?

Tags: python, pymupdf, pdf-extraction

import fitz

doc = fitz.open(""

List item

)

for page in doc:
print(page.search_for("Bank Account"))

> this program is for get dimensions of given text. i want to do reverse of it, find text using its dimensions.

Comment: Dimensions in what sense?  Show an example.

Comment: If we run above code then we will get dimensions of text

Comment: There are a lot of PDF reader libraries for Python.  Perhaps one of the others can do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) First get the rectangular coordinates `rect(x_0,y_0,x_1,y_1)` of the text you want to extract.

2.) Use the syntax `Page.get_text("text",clip=rect)`. Place you rectangular coordinates into the clip.

For more go to the [link](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/page.html#Page.get_text).

Answer (score -1):

```
import fitz

doc = fitz.open("")

rect = fitz.Rect(value) #add dimension in place of value

for page in doc: 
  print(page.get_textbox(rect))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it solves the problem.